# How can I set up a profile page to view user status updates?

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I'm working on a Facebook clone so I'm going to have multiple users. I have my `profile` page set up in an ejs page called `profile`. Currently, when I view the page it shows all the status updates however, I've only tested with a single user. I have all the status updates stored in a Schema called `Status`. When I log into my second user, make a status update and then view the profile, I see every status inside the `Status` schema. This would be like logging into Facebook and having all your friends status updates show up on your page. I want to have it so when I view a users page, I only see their status updates but I'm struggling to figure out how.

`Profile.ejs // loops through Schema. This is where I'm having trouble`

```
<% status_list.forEach(function(status) { %>
  <div class="status">
    <p><%= status.content %></p>
    <button class="like-btn">♡</button>
  </div>
<% }); %>
```

`Status Schema`

```
const statusSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  content: { type: String, required: true },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
```

`User Schema`

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  username: String,
  password: String,
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
```

`Router GET for user page`

```
router.get("/:user", function (req, res, next) {
  const user = req.user.username;
  Status.find({}, "content createdAt")
    .sort({ title: 1 })
    .exec(function (err, list_status) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      res.render("profile", { status_list: list_status, user: user });
    });
  console.log(user);
});
```

`Router POST for user page`

```
router.post("/:user", [
  body("content", "Content must not be empty.")
    .trim()
    .isLength({ min: 1 })
    .escape(),
  // Process request after validation and sanitization.
  (req, res, next) => {
    // Extract the validation errors from a request.
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    // Create an article object with escaped and trimmed data.
    const status = new Status({
      content: req.body.content,
      author: req.body.author,
    });

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      // Get all authors and genres for form.
      async.parallel((err, results) => {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        res.render("profile", {
          author: author.username,
          content: content,
          status,
          errors: errors.array(),
        });
      });
      return;
    }

    // Data from form is valid. Save article.
    status.save((err) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      res.redirect("/");
    });
  },
]);
```